# Storage in laravel says symlink - no such file

Tags: php, laravel

I deployed laravel app on shared hosting in public_html/app folder. Here is everything from public folder. In /../../files I have rest of files. When I do php artisan storage:link in files folder my console says

```
[ErrorException]                      
  symlink(): No such file or directory
```

On localhost I upload files to storage/uploads folder. What to do now? I tried to change links but nothing works for me...

Comment: why `storage` and not in `public/assets` ? I am sure there is path issue try another way

Comment: css and js files i have in public but i mean for example images which users uploads are in storage/uploads/images/

Comment: Use `storage_path()` instead

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: @Programmmereg, are you renaming the `public` folder? if so try to rename it back to `public`

Answer (score 240):

1. Go to `/public` directory and run:

   `rm storage`
2. Go to Laravel root directory and run:

   `php artisan storage:link`

---

Edited on May 1st 2018

This problem comes when laravel project is moved/copied to some other folder.

The storage link is still there thus causing the exception error. public/storage folder exists and points to wrong location and it needs to be deleted with `rm storage` command.

After that run `php artisan storage:link` in terminal and it will create the storage link.

This needs to be done EVERY time when laravel is moved/copied/deployed!

Comment: Also, if you use Laravel Orchid you may also need `rm public/orchid && ./artisan orchid:link`

Comment: Also be careful if your deployment script removes the storage symlink and then FAILS, and then you run it again and the symlink is already removed, your deployment script may throw an error trying to delete something that's already gone, and fail. Be careful of that edge case.

Answer (score 22):

I'm face same error when use share hosting and my public directory move to public_html or different directory
like : 
project directory in root name "project"
and public directory in root name "public_html"

when run artisan command by Artisan::call('storage:link'); then face this error.

Solution: 
 1st need to bind your public directory in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider register method

```
 $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path('../public_html');
 });
```

Now run the command its working fine

Answer (score 22):

Just in case your down here still without an answer.

I had trouble because I did the symlink locally, then copied the files to the server. In order to make it work I did the following:

```
$  cd path/to/laravel/root

// if public does not exist, first create it.
$  cd public

// if public/storage does not exist, first create it.
$  rm -r storage

$  cd ..

// Now it should work
$  php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: That's famous, creating a directory to remove it, great idea!

Answer (score 13):

This usually happens after moving Laravel app to another directory

The actual storage directory is "/AppName/storage/app/public/"

Laravel creates a symbolic link pointing to actual storage dir  "/AppName/public/storage"

Other meaning

> "/AppName/public/storage" points to => "/AppName/storage/app/public/"

On changing root app directory to "/AnotherAppName/" symlink will still point to the old path

> "/AnotherAppName/public/storage" => "/AppName/storage/app/public/"

my solution is to manually update the symlink using

```
ln -sfn /AnotherAppName/storage/app/public/ /AnotherAppName/public/storage
```

Answer (score 8):

Anyone coming in the future using Laravel Forge. I had this error when I renamed my domain name in Forge.

[image: storage:link error]

The solution was to go into the public directory and delete the existing symlink which had been copied over from the original domain.

[image: public symlink to storage]

After this symlink had been deleted, I was able to run `php artisan storage:link` again and this worked correctly.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience! This was exactly my case and you saved my day :)

Answer (score 7):

create new php file and put this code on the file:

```
<?php
symlink('/home/CpanelUser/storage/app/public', '/home/CpanelUserpublic_html/storage');
?>
```

"CpanelUser" change to youre cpanel user name or host name.

Upload this file to public_html folder (www) of site
execute file with write site name+this file in browser
done!

Example:
My file name is symlink.php and site name is www.anysite.com
upload symlink.php to public_html folder in host and get web address in browser

http://www.anysite.com/symlink.php

after execute this file storage folder creite in public folder in laravel and link to storage folder in app.

Answer (score 6):

To fix this error on your server, change directory to the public and remove the symbolic link for the storage folder.

The following commands will help you remove the symbolic link from the **public folder**:

```
cd public

rm storage
```

After removing the symbolic link go back to the **root folder** using with the command below:

```
cd ..
```

Now create the symbolic link with the following command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

After running the command successfully, you should get the following message

```
The [public/storage] directory has been linked.
```

I hope this post helps you.

[SYMLINK(): No Such File or Directory Laravel](https://anansewaa.com/symlink-no-such-file-or-directory-laravel/)

Answer (score 4):

Follow these three steps:

1. Remove storage file from **public** folder.

   > rm public/storage
2. If storage folder is there in your root directory, remove public file inside app folder.

   > rm storage/app/public
3. Run link command

   > php artisan storage:link

Comment: Removing the `storage/app/public` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

if issue is not fixed yet.
Do These Steps:

1. Delete storage link from public folder or run these commands.

a)

> cd public

b) `rm storage`

2. Goto storage folder and check if `app/public`
   folder exists otherwise create new folder.
3. Check if the error is fixed.
4. If these steps not fixed your issue delete `storage` folder and create new `storage` folder containing all necessary folders on it.

`storage` folder contains:
`app, framework,logs`

`app` contains: `public`
`framework` contains: `cache, data,sessions,testing, views`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the **`APP_URL`** configuration in **`.env`** file is set correctly. after that run following command line:

```sh
php artisan config:cache
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to config/filesystem.php  in the symbolic links section in my case I removed public_path  function and wrote my own path in it  then run php artisan storage:link command again.

```
 'links' => [
    '/var/www/storage' => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Add this inside web.php and then hit this '`BASE_URL/linkstorage`' URL once.
Now check the storage folder will be created inside the public folder. This will resolve your issue.

```
Route::get('/linkstorage', function () {
    $targetFolder = base_path().'/storage/app/public';
    $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage';
    symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that te symlink not was placed in /localhost/public/ but in /localhost/storage/app/
When i removed the symlink in /localhost/storage/app/ the artisan command works like a charm

In my code i placed this to prevent creating the wrong symlink

```
Route::get('/clear', function () {
    Storage::deleteDirectory('public');
    Storage::makeDirectory('public');

    Artisan::call('route:clear');
    Artisan::call('storage:link', [] );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using shared hosting or you have deployed your project on a server with cPanel or DirectAdmin, you probably have a `public_html` instead of a `public` folder.

So one thing we usually do is change the Laravel `public` folder to `public_html`.
and then we go to our `AppServiceProvider` and bind the new path with the help of code below:

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', fn() => base_path('/public_html'));
```

But you should know the configuration files load before these register methods at your providers, so you have also to bind this before your kernel bootstrap your config files.

in order to do that, open `index.php` and write the code bellow after the `$app` variable defined:

```
$app->bind('path.public', fn() => base_path('/public_html'));
```

I know this might not seem a standard way, but It is working perfectly fine, and I haven't found any critical issue for it yet!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to index.php

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() { return __DIR__; });
```

then on routes/web.php

add this

```
Route::get('/linkstorage', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

Then run the link

Answer (score 0):

Delete the existing storage symbolic link (`public/storage`) and then run 
`php artisan storage:link` command again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that because I had moved all of the /public Laravel files to public_html (on my shared server), that the /public Laravel directory no longer existed.

After making a new "public" directory, I was able to successfully run the 'php artisan storage:link' command.

Answer (score 0):

more instant i improve the answer of @suresh-pangeni

```
mv storage storage.bak // just for backup
```

```
mkdir -p storage/{app/public,framework/{cache,data,sessions,testing,views},logs}
```

```
php artisan storage:link
```

now its work
dont forget to
Go to `/public` directory and run:
then
`rm storage` before run on above command.

> ☺  pa storage:link
> production 9999 ✗ The [public/storage] directory has been linked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is above but in separate parts, do one and two. Adding the route makes it easier for use case on external servers like shared hosts for example, thanks everyone

1. Go to config/filesystem.php in the symbolic links section in my case I removed public_path function and wrote my own path in it then run php artisan storage:link command again.

```js
'links' => [
   '/var/www/storage' => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

2. For create storage link without terminal command(get at url)

```js
Route::get('/linkstorage', function () {
    $targetFolder = base_path().'/storage/app/public';
    $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage';
    symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue normally happens when you changed the folder location after you generated your first symbolic link, I solved this isse by following the below steps:

1. Go in to the public folder and delete the storage folder(It will be labeled with red flag)
2. After deleting the storage folder, run **php artisan storage:link** and the issue will be solved

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps:**

*Step-1: server.php*

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public_html'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public_html/index.php';
```

*Step-2: App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php*

```
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //Public folder name changed with public_html
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function(){
        return base_path().'/public_html';
    });
}
```

> It is allow you to run the usual command `php artisan serve`

*Step-3: config\filesystems.php*

```
'links' => [
    base_path('public_html/storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

> To get the storage symbolic link properly with `php artisan storage:link`

**Remember to change the path if is not public_html like for me**

Answer (score 0):

If someone faces the same error in Docker and Laravel9, try by deleting `storage` file in `public` folder and executing `php artisan storage:link` again. In my case it is 0KB.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had added more than one symbolic link added to `config/filesystems`, one of the links is meant to be created in a subfolder but the parent folder doesn't exist ie the link leads to `public/users/uploads` but `public/users` folder does not exist.

So the first step was to create public/users folder before running `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted `public/storage` file and has not fixed, yet. Try this  `composer dump-autoload`.