# Why my laravel says that symlink - no such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, symlink

I just uploaded my laravel app to shared hosting and I am trying to do php artisan storage:link, but console says: symlink(): No such file or directory.

I am also trying doing this:

```
 ln -s ~/domains/xyz.pl/sce/storage/app/public/ ~/domains/xyz.pl/public_html/sce/storage/
```

In the past that was working, but not today. I can't see any images in my project.

What my log says?

```
ErrorException: symlink(): No such file or directory in /home/rvsky/domains/xyz.pl/sce/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:217
```

What to do to make it working? I have not idea now, I have been trying almost everything...

Comment: This looks like it might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409417/storage-in-laravel-says-symlink-no-such-file

Comment: Have u tried deleting public/storage
Again, php artisan storage:link

Answer (score 1):

Are you a sudo user, or do you have access to the directory where the symlink is being created? Maybe you can find your answer in this discussion [Public Storage...](http://%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/34#issuecomment-208895323) Suggesting to add the snippet to your composer.json file.

```js
"post-install-cmd": [
    "ln -sr storage/app/public public/storage"
],
```