# Create a symlink top of the other symlink

Tags: php, linux, laravel, hosting, symlink

I'm using GoDaddy shared hosting server to upload Laravel project from my local. I decided to use symlink to link "laravel/public" directory to GoDaddy "public_html" by using Putty instead of changing directories within the hosting server. Then, I realized that I need to link the picture storage folder inside "laravel/public". 
so currently it looks like the below:

ln -s laravel/storage/app/public/cover_images laravel/public/storage/cover_images

ls->[~/laravel/public/storage] cover_images@

ln -s laravel/public public_html

ls-> [~] public_html@

ls-> [~/public_html/storage] cover_images@

it works for displaying everything but cover_images@. It looks to me fine by seeing directories. 
If you see the image html source, it looks like

`<img src='/storage/cover_images/g_1540352310.png'>`

and doesn't display it.

Please help me!

Answer (score -1):

I just found the why it got 404 error. So this is NOT the symlink issue. 
please read the posted answer.

[Storage in laravel says symlink - no such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409417/storage-in-laravel-says-symlink-no-such-file)

thanks,