# symlink(): No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, symlink, laravel-filesystem

In my laravel project i have put my files in storage directory. Some of my files i need to access from public folder inside storage directory i.e. **storage/app/public/images**

> In my server i have put the laravel **public** folder inside
>   **public_html** and other folders outside of **public_html**.

As for accessing storage file publicly i need to run the following command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

But when i run the above command in server i got following Error:

> In Filesystem.php line 228: symlink(): No such file or directory

How to access public folder inside **storage directory** when laravel public folder inside **public_html** on server?

Comment: check this link if shared hosting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409417/storage-in-laravel-says-symlink-no-such-file/55699608#55699608

Answer (score 1):

You changed the laravel default public folder to public_html. So you should first fix laravel public directory path **and then** run that artisan command. The solution to fix laravel public directory path is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30198781/4835268

Answer (score 0):

The "public" folder may sometimes be missing from the storage/app directory. Create a public folder in the storage/app directory.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the storage folder and files and run the command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: rm public/storage, not the one outside.